# Passing a const reference as a function parameter in a class member function

Tags: c++, class, const-reference

Suppose we have a class called `Line` that contains the following modifier that assigns a value to a class data member.

`void Start(const Point &start);`

The line class contains two data members called start and end which are both Point objects. Since the `start` variable in the function parameter is a reference, and I implement it as follows:

`void Line::Start(const Point &start) {
    m_start = start;
}`

In the main function I have the following.

`Line line;
 Point start(1, 1);
 line.Start(start);`

Would the `m_start` data member now refer directly to the `start` `Point` object in the main function since it was passed by reference?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `m_start`? If `m_start` is a `Point` then no, the value is copied. If it is a const reference then you have a compile error. You need to initialize const members and references in the initializer list.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to test this yourself, such as changing the point after and having another class method which outputs data from the passed `Point` reference to see if it is the same `Point`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the m_start data member now refer directly to the start Point
>   object in the main function since it was passed by reference?

No.  One of the properties of C++ references (and one of the ways in which their behavior differs from that of pointers) is that it's impossible to *reseat* a reference -- that is, you can't make a reference that was 'referring to' one thing later 'refer to' a different thing.  (And of course if your `m_start` member variable was of type `Point` rather than type `Point &`, then there's no reference to attempt-to-reseat anyway)

Instead, `start`'s copy-constructor will be invoked to copy `start`'s contents into your `m_start` member-variable.

The upshot is that your `Start()` method will behave exactly like a similarly-implemented `void Line::Start(Point start)` method would, with the following exceptions:

1. In your `const Point &` version of `Start()`, no separate/method-local copy of the Point object is made
2. In your `const Point &` version of `Start()`, trying to modify `start` from within the method would be a compile-time error (whereas in the pass-by-value version, the code inside `Start()` could modify the argument, but the modifications would never be visible outside of the `Start()` function since they'd only modify the local variable/parameter)